# Joomla is creating extra div containers in Modules

Tags: html, css, joomla

I have just installed a local copy of Joomla to build a website.
When I add a module into a position it is adding 3 containing divs around content, is this a setting in the backend how how can it be fixed?

I have attached a picture to further explain my situation:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The layout of the `mod_menu` in Joomla 3.6.4 does not contain any encapsulating divs. It might be that you have an overridden layout in `templates/joomlatemplate/html/modules/mod_menu/default.php`

If the above file doesn't exist in your `joomlatemplate` (which is the name of the template that you're using), then likely the problem exists in your `index.php` file under `templates/joomlatemplate`. The encapsulating divs are likely there and you should edit that file to remove them.

Note: Make sure you back up any file that you want to modify.